# Is it possible to keep the action when exchange activities?

Tags: android

Assume we have 2 activities: **A**(tabhost activity) and **B**.

If I do some action at **A** , and then change to **B**.

Something like ...

step 1. check the radio button on **A**
step 2. change to **B** without doing finish() **A**
step 3. doing finish() **B** and turn back to **A**
However, when I turn back to **A**, the setting of radio button had been changed to initial.

Is it possible to keep the setting on **A** when I turn back from **B** to **A**?

Any help is as always appreciated. Thanks : )

Comment: use fragment http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: yeah it is possible. For that you must extend ActivityGroup

Comment: You can save the instance of the page using onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android

Comment: @Vinay  i will try , my problem is to use A's radio button to run a server ,and will have client's connect state, i wonder know whether use onRestoreInstanceState() will open server again or lost client's connect state